# Kotlin - AsyncTask doesn't fetch JSON data from API link and doesn't show it in the app

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-asynctask

So I have written following kotlin code for android application to fetch data from " api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=london&appid=c2b58047e18bbe39e7e547e9083f4824 ". The data in this link is of London city. Application is supposed to take a city name from user and edit the url "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=**{CITY NAME}**&appid=c2b58047e18bbe39e7e547e9083f4824" as per city and fetch the JSON file from the URL. I have added Toast pop ups to check for bugs. Application shows Toast pop up after submit button but it doesn't show any update or display any data once AsyncTask class object is called.

**TLDR: App doesn't fetch the JSON data, nor shows any update after the MyAsyncTask is called when it should display the temperature of the city.**

Here's the code:

```
package com.awesome.mystartup

import android.content.Context
import android.os.AsyncTask
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Toast
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import org.json.JSONObject
import java.io.BufferedReader
import java.io.InputStream
import java.io.InputStreamReader
import java.net.HttpURLConnection
import java.net.URL
import kotlin.Exception

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var city:String? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        buSubmit.setOnClickListener{

            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Button clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            city = tvCityName.text.toString().toLowerCase()
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "city:"+city,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            val tempUrl = "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+city+"&appid=c2b58047e18bbe39e7e547e9083f4824"

**//Following Toast is the last Toast displayed**
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, tempUrl,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() 
            **MyAsyncTask().execute(tempUrl)**  
        }
    }

    inner class MyAsyncTask:AsyncTask<String,String,String>(){
        override fun onPreExecute() {
            //Fired before task is started
            super.onPreExecute()

        }

        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: String?): String {

            //Get HTTP Call
            //UI can't access this as it's in background.
            //To make sure UI shows it, call publishProgress(string)
            try {
                val url = URL(params[0]) // Params is kind of an array. [0] element has url
                val urlConnect = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
                urlConnect.connectTimeout = 7000 // Wait for 7 seconds for result, if not received, throw exception
                var inString = ConvertStreamToString(urlConnect.inputStream)
                publishProgress(inString)
            }
            catch (ex:Exception){
//                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Error in doInBackground",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            return ""
        }

        override fun onProgressUpdate(vararg values: String?) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(*values)
            try {
                //Convert string to JSON
//                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Progress running",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                var json = JSONObject(values[0])
                val main = json.getJSONObject("main")
                val temp = main.getString("temp")
                var tempFloat = temp.toFloat()
                tvShowTemp.text = "Temperature of the "+city+" is: "+tempFloat
            }catch (ex:Exception){
//                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Error in onProgressUpdate",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }

        override fun onPostExecute(result: String?) {
            //fired after task is executed
            super.onPostExecute(result)
        }
    }



    //To convert input stream to String, following function is used
    fun ConvertStreamToString(inputstream:InputStream):String{
        //Take the input inputstream and convert it to InputStreamReader. Then convert that to BufferedReader and store it
        val bufferReader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inputstream))
        var line:String
        var allString = ""

        try {
            do {
                line = bufferReader.readLine()
                if (line != null) {
                    allString += line
                }
            } while (line != null)


        } catch (ex:Exception){
//            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Error in ConvertStreamToString",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        return allString
    }


}
```

Comment: You are missing the  `https://` from the URL, then don't log any exceptions that would help you figure out what went wrong

Comment: i think you should edit "http://" to your URL